# How to change title of active window using wmctrl

Tags: window, fluxbox, window-title, wmctrl

I'm using fluxbox window manager and recently I've added "always on top" shortcut to my "keys" file.

`Mod1 a :ExecCommand wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above`

But I'd like to know if window state is "on top". Can I somehow add some strnig to window's title using wmctrl that would inform me about this ?

Comment: Did you read `man wmctrl`? The `-T` option will be good. Or do you have another problem?